# Scilab Ilib_for_link

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, scilab

I would like to ask you for a little help,I dont know how to fix this.

Here is description: I have installed Ubuntu 15 and Scilab 5.5.2 there, and I want to link and compile C file wih function ilib_for_link: 
here is result:

```
-->ilib_for_link('termo','termo.c',[],'c','','loader.sce','','','-g'); 
Generate a loader file 
Generate a Makefile 
ilib_gen_Make: Copy compilation files (Makefile*, libtool...) to TMPDIR
ilib_gen_Make: Copy termo.c to TMPDIR 
ilib_gen_Make: configure : Generate Makefile. 
ilib_gen_Make: Modification of the Makefile in TMPDIR. 
Running the Makefile 
Generate a cleaner file
```

Everything worked fine. But I need to run this in Ubuntu 14.04 in exact Scilab 5.5.2 and there happened one error:

```
-->ilib_for_link('termo','termo.c',[],'c','','loader.sce','','','-g') 
Generate a loader file 
Generate a Makefile 
ilib_gen_Make: Copy compilation files (Makefile*, libtool...) to TMPDIR 
ilib_gen_Make: Copy termo.c to TMPDIR 
ilib_gen_Make: Modification of the Makefile in TMPDIR.
Running the Makefile !--error 10000 ilib_compile: Could not find the built 
library '.libs/libtermo.so'. at line 144 of function ilib_compile called by : at line 94 of function ilib_for_link called by : oader.sce','','',''
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Try going to TMPDIR and see if anything is generated there:

`chdir(TMPDIR)`
`isfile('.libs/libtermo.so')`

Comment: And maybe also check file permissions of TMPDIR

Comment: Also see bugs: [14503](http://bugzilla.scilab.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14503) and [14180](http://bugzilla.scilab.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14180)

Comment: permissions for TMDIR were 777, and in TMPDIR folder there were generated fileslike makefile, but no libtermo.so